# Which sortable npm package is best for the image list in react 17?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a sortable image list using some npm package.
I googled but I couldn't find any remarkable resource.
If I find some package like react-sortable-hoc ,react-sortable and some others then such packages doesn't full compliance with react 17 version.

If I use react-sortable-hoc then there are many errors while using `"array-move"` and related to array modification.

Can any one suggest some popular react 17 sortable package and an example?

Following is my package.json file.

```
{
    "name": "test-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.7.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "faker": "^5.5.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
        "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.7",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.12.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
        "yup": "^0.32.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
}
```

I want to make a sortable image list by drag and drop feature.
Thank you

Comment: Go to the dependencies. the base of react-upload-gallery is same as react-sortable-hoc. I never tried it but still 'll try. The search result bring the top result as react-sortable-hoc and React Beautiful DnD. React Beautiful DnD support react 17 but require a lot logic to maintain it and only support horizontal or vertical not both. and there many limitations in it

Comment: I never tried it too, but your comment might help someone who is knowledgeable in `reactjs` to give a better hint...